# Print multiple occurrences in a string

Tags: python, string, if-statement, find-occurrences

I'm trying to write a function where the input has a keyword that occurs multiple times in a string and will print the stuff that has double quotation marks between them after the keyword. Essentially...

```
Input= 'alkfjjiekeyword "someonehelpmepls"fjioee... omgsos someonerandom help helpppmeeeeeee keyword"itonlygivesmeoneinsteadofmultiple"... sadnesssadness!sadness' 

Output= someonehelpmepls 

itonlygivesmeoneinsteadofmultiple
```

If its possible to have the outputs as its own line that would be better.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def getEm(s): 

    h = s.find('keyword') 

    if h == -1 
       return -1 

    else: 
       begin = s.find('"',h) 
       end = s.find('"', begin+1) 
       result = s[begin +1:end] 
    print (result)
```

Please don't suggest import. I do not know how to do that nor know what it is, I am a beginner.

Comment: import just means "I want to use this really useful thing in the library of cool stuff".

Answer (score 2):

Let's take some sample input:

```
>>> Input= 'alkfjjiekeyword "someonehelpmepls"fjioee... omgsos someonerandom help helpppmeeeeeee keyword"itonlygivesmeoneinsteadofmultiple"... sadnesssadness!sadness'
```

I believe that one `"` was missing from the sample input, so I added it.

As I understand it, you want to get the strings in double-quotes that follow the word `keyword`.  If that is the case, then:

```
def get_quoted_after_keyword(input):
    results = []
    split_by_keyword = input.split('keyword')
    # you said no results before the keyword
    for s in split_by_keyword[1:]:
        split_by_quote = s.split('"')
        if len(split_by_quote) > 1:
            # assuming you want exactly one quoted result per keyword
            results.append(split_by_quote[1])
    return results

>print('\n'.join(get_quoted_after_keyword(Input))
>someonehelpmepls
>itonlygivesmeoneinsteadofmultiple
```

#### How it works

Let's look at the first piece:

```
>>> Input.split('keyword')
['alkfjjie',
 ' "someonehelpmepls"fjioee... omgsos someonerandom help helpppmeeeeeee ',
 '"itonlygivesmeoneinsteadofmultiple"... sadnesssadness!sadness']
```

By splitting `Input` on `keyword`, we get, in this case, three strings.  The second string to the last are all strings that follow the word `keyword`.  To get those strings without the first string, we use subscripting:

```
>>> Input.split('keyword')[1:]
[' "someonehelpmepls"fjioee... omgsos someonerandom help helpppmeeeeeee ',
 '"itonlygivesmeoneinsteadofmultiple"... sadnesssadness!sadness']
```

Now, our next task is to get the part of these strings that is in double-quotes.  To do that, we split each of these strings on `"`.  The second string, the one numbered `1`, will be the string in double quotes.  As a simpler example, let's take these strings:

```
>>> [s.split('"')[1] for s in ('"one"otherstuff', ' "two"morestuff')]
['one', 'two']
```

Next, we put these two steps together:

```
>>> [s.split('"')[1] for s in Input.split('keyword')[1:]]
['someonehelpmepls', 'itonlygivesmeoneinsteadofmultiple']
```

We now have the strings that we want.  The last step is to print them out nicely, one per line:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(s.split('"')[1] for s in Input.split('keyword')[1:]))
someonehelpmepls
itonlygivesmeoneinsteadofmultiple
```

**Limitation:** this approach assumes that `keyword` never appears inside the double-quoted strings.

Comment: Looks promising, but you can get list index out of range pretty easily, and you assume the correct answer is to give one quoted result per keyword.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yes, there are many hypotheticals but, without a clear problem statement, we can only guess at the correct code.  Should it print all double-quotes strings?  Or, should a double-quoted string not preceded by `keyword` be considered an error?  Or, should such double-quoted strings be ignored?  The possibilities are many.

Comment: That's fair. But the list index out of range still bothers me. You could split them on separate lines, have easier code for a newbie to read, and have a temp variable to check for len.

Comment: @KennyOstrom OK.  If you are inspired to write a good answer for the OP, I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: Maybe I just propose an edit with that one fix. :)

Comment: Thank you everyone! Can someone explain what '\n' does? I have never seen this.

Comment: In Python,  `\n` is the newline character: it marks the end of a line.